# LuaLaTeX issue using minted (continued from ...)

Tags: luatex, minted, shell-escape

In [issue with minted and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663921/issue-with-minted-and-lualatex) there is a discussion in the comments underneath the question and an answer confirming the issue. Since I can confirm the issue as well and have additional information to share, it seems better to continue the question than to extend the comments or provide a non-answer.

I used another MWE but one comparable to mbert's in the original question on two machines:

1. Desktop CPU i9 32GB RAM Windows 11 V22H2 TeXStudio 4.4.1 MikTeX 2.9 updated Python 3.11 Pygments 2.14
2. Laptop CPU AMD Athlon II 8GB RAM Xubuntu 22.04 TeXStudio 4.0.1 MikTeX 2.9 updated Python 3.11 Pygments 2.14

MWE used on both machines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

    \begin{minted}{c}
        int main() {
            printf("hello, world");
            return 0;
        }
    \end{minted}

\end{document}
```

I obtained the following results:

1. Compiling with PDFLatex gave the desired result. The code in the `minted` environment was set properly. The additional directory created by `minted` contained two files: one with a long string name and one called `default.pygstyle`of about 7kB.
2. Compiling with XeXeTeX provided an output in which all spaces and tabs were shown as `^^I` and the colouring of the code was absent. The `^^I` is defined in the `fancyvrb` package. This occurred on both machines.
3. Compiling with LuaLaTeX was successful on the laptop (Xubuntu), but *not* on the desktop (Windows). The directory was created by `minted` under Windows, but contained only the file `default.pygstyle` of 0kB. An empty one thus.
4. Compiling with PDFLaTeX followed by compiling with LuaLaTeX still gave the *!Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize` installed to use this package* error, but did give a correct output. That second compiling used the directory created by the first one.

The difference in the logfile between the Xubuntu version and the Windows version is in:

```
runsystem(for ^%i in (pygmentize.exe pygmentize.bat pygmentize.cmd) do set > min
ted_test.aex <nul: /p x=^%~$PATH:i>> minted_test.aex)...failed 

runsystem(del minted_test.aex)...executed
```

Under Windows the result of the shell escape comes back as **failed**, whereas under Xubuntu the result is **executed**. Both machines use the same `shellesc`:

```
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
```

To me it seems that there some kind of obscure issue in `-shell-escape` when using `shellesc` in LuaLaTeX on a Windows machine.

Hopefully someone more knowledgeable about the inner workings of `shellesc` on Windows command line can shed some light on this issue.

*Note:* Of course I can compile my `.tex` files on my laptop and drink a cup of coffee or more, but it would be nice to see the issue on my desktop solved.

**Additional information**
Following instructions in the comments of the original question I found the following issue in the **path** statement when compiling using *LuaLaTeX* under Windows:

When I use the line `\ShellEscape{path > path.txt}` in *PDFLaTeX* I get a complete `path` statement in *path.txt* - as it should be. **However** when I use *LuaLaTeX* *path.txt* contains only one line: `PATH=C:\Open Source\MikTeX\miktex\bin\x64\` which obviously isn't correct. So LuaLaTeX somehow purges the correct Windows path statement and replaces it with the MikTeX location.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{shellesc}

\begin{document}
    \ShellEscape{path > path.txt}
\end{document}
```

The *MikTeX* [documentation on LuaLaTeX](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-luatex.html) contains the following lines in the **Options** section:

*When the LuaTeX executable starts, it looks for the --lua commandline option. If there is no --lua option, the commandline is interpreted in a similar fashion as in traditional pdfTeX. But if the option is present, LuaTeX will enter an alternative mode of commandline parsing in comparison to the standard MiKTeX programs. The presence of --lua makes most of other options unreliable, because the Lua initialization file can disable path searching and/or hook functions into various callbacks.*

In my TeXStudio setup, there is no switch `--lua` present in the LuaLaTeX command. It just reads:

`lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape  %.tex`

Comment: well I have no problems on my windows with miktex. On my system the test reports a failure too, imho correctly as I have only pygmentize.exe and the other two call should fail. Is something unusual with your pathes? Do you have non-ascii or spaces or something similar in them?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you mentioned in the other question that you don't have problems. I followed the instructions given in the `minted` manual and on the website of python to install both python and pygments. There are spaces in both path environments, but no non-ascii characters. As PDFLatex compiling is successful, I wouldn't think those spaces should be a problem.

Comment: BTW: can you elaborate on *only pigmentize.exe* and the remark *the other two call should fail*?  If that is a difference between your Windows setup and mine, we might be on the track of something.

Comment: the for loop tests pygmentize.exe, pygmentize.bat and pygmentize.bat. I have only the first.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have two `.sty` files in the minted map called `minted.sty` (48kB) and `minted1.sty` (10kB). Both files contain a section that starts with `\newcommand\TestAppExists[1]` followed by `\ifwindows` (line 180 resp. 65). In that section there is a `\ShellEscape{ .... }` that calls on testing `#1.exe #1.bat #1.com`. In the following `else` section `\ShellEscape{ .... }` only contains a call to `#1` . Guess that section is used on Apple and Linux installations.

Comment: sure, shell-escape and pygmentize detection is different on windows and linux. But your minted detects both correctly on windows, and it also creates the folder, it is the next step that fails. So you should better look what is going on with the commands on line 512 and following of minted.sty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer please check the updated information. Somehow the path statement in your installation seems to remain intact, whereas mine (and that of several others) is changed. Why and how that occurs is a complete mystery to me.

Comment: I have not found a solution, but I have the same problem and wanted to note that the problem has also been discussed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673564/shellescape-fails-in-certain-cases-with-lualatex